# Is there any way to capture exact line number where exception happened in python

Tags: python, python-3.6

Hi is there any way to get the exact line number where the exception happen? because i am using a wrapper method and in actual method there are many lines of code and i am getting a very generic exception and not sure where exactly it is happening . Eg code as below,

```
import sys
def test(**kwargs):
    print (kwargs)
    abc

def wraper_test(**kwargs):
    try:
        test(**kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        exception_type, exception_object, exception_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        print(exception_object.tfline_no)

wraper_test(hello="test", value="lsdf")
```

Now in the exception line number what i am getting is for test(**kwargs) and not the exact location where the exception is generated in this case "abc" which is inside the test method.

Is there any way to capture the exact line number in exception when we are using wrapper method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: the traceback library allows you to get a longer stack trace with more line numbers (this shows the real error is on line 5).

```
import sys, traceback

def test(**kwargs):
    print (kwargs)
    abc

def wrapper_test(**kwargs):
    try:
        test(**kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        exception_type, exception_object, exception_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        traceback.print_tb(exception_traceback, limit=2, file=sys.stdout)

wrapper_test(hello="test", value="lsdf")
```

Comment: You can also get the line numbers out of the traceback object, if you want to process them further